# jQuery datepicker shows input on iPhone with Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, safari, datepicker

I used readOnly and it works without problem on desktop (both Chrome and Safari work fine).

However on mobile Safari, if the user clicks on the datepicker, it shows the cursor blinking in the input.

Any suggestions on how to prevent the input focus on mobile would be much appreciated.

Comment: That's how a read only input works. You can click inside it and select the text, but you cannot modify it. You would have to override the intended functionality, which goes against using `readonly` in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try one of the following.

CSS to prevent selection:

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

or if you are using jQuery, you could try to prevent the click:

```
$(".my_input_box").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Launch your datepicker manually here
}
```

Either of these two help?

Comment: Awesome! I tried the css one and it worked. it seemed to have some other effects to the datepicker but i will figure out that. Thanks a lot!